# DNS records config for .IT (italian) domain name

Tags: dns

Recently i buy domain name mysite.IT but i can't use this domain on other web hosting.
Problem is i cant change NS, i only have option to change DNS records (paid option) from tol.it

I'm confused in type of records i what i need to change to work domain on other web server.

I atach 2 screen, maby somebody has similar problem i can help me. THX a lot
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your website is on the **www.domainname.it** address. From your screenshot it looks like this is a **CNAME** record pointing to the **domainname.it** address.

Therefore if you want to point the website elsewhere, you'll need to **change the A record for your domainname.it address** to point to whatever IP address your new server is on.